# Sub item in ListView not showing up using Windows API in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two functions to init the listview and one to add entries to the list view. I created a struct that holds the column information.

```
struct LISTVIEW_COLUMN
{
    const TCHAR * Title;
    int           Width;
};
```

This is how I am creating the column struct

```
static struct LISTVIEW_COLUMN lvNames[] =
{
    { TEXT("Name"), 150 },
    { TEXT("Last"), 125 }
};
```

Then I have the functions defined as follows.

```
void InitListView(HWND hListView, LISTVIEW_COLUMN * lvColumn, int nCols) 
{

    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

    // Create the columns
    for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
        LVCOLUMN lvc;
        lvc.pszText  = (TCHAR *)lvColumn[col].Title;
        lvc.cx       = lvColumn[col].Width;
        lvc.mask     = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, col, &lvc);
    }
}

void NetPCAddListViewRow(HWND hListView, TCHAR * name, TCHAR * lastName)
{
    LVITEM     lvItem;

    // Add item (name)
    lvItem.mask     = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;
    lvItem.iItem    = 0;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.iImage   = 0;
    lvItem.pszText  = (TCHAR *)name;
    lvItem.iItem    = ListView_InsertItem(hListView, &lvItem);

// Just using "testing" right now to see it as a subitem
    lvItem.iSubItem += 1;
    lvItem.pszText  = _T("testing");
    ListView_SetItem(hListView, &lvItem);
}
```

The columns show up just fine and the first column "name" gets added to but I cant get anything to show up as a subitem in that column? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong except you're not initialising the `LVITEM` structure (although in theory this shouldn't matter because of the `mask` field). Does `ListView_SetItemText()` work to set the sub-item text? Maybe see if you can post a [MCVE].

Comment: Hmm, I just tried using ListView_SetItemText() and same thing. I did check the return of ListView_SetItem() and it's returning '0'. I don't know why that would fail though when InsertItem works just fine? I'll see if I can come up with a small example reproduces it.

Comment: Try initialising the `LVITEM` to 0 just as a test as well.

Comment: "*I did check the return of `ListView_SetItem()` and it's returning '0'*" - then you are definitely doing something wrong.  I agree with Jonathan. *ALWAYS* zero out API structures before using them.  Also, just to check, are you setting the ListView to Report view?

Comment: Just set LVCOLUMN lvc =  { 0 }; and LVITEM lvItem = { 0 }; and still does it. @RemyLebeau Yeah, just trying to figure out where atm now. :\

Comment: Like Jonathan said, please provide a [mcve] showing the problem in action. The code you have shown is fine, so the problem has to be in code you have not shown yet.

Comment: I just wrote a very similar program recently, and I did two things differently. I set the iSubItem member of the columns and for some reason I stopped specifying LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT.

Comment: @Stuart good catch on needing to set `LVCOLUMN::iSubItem`, you should post that as an answer. On the other hand, I use `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` all the time, it works fine, and doesn't affect a column's ability to display text.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [How to Add List-View Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298344(v=vs.85).aspx) example on MSDN you will see that they set the `iSubItem` member and the `LVCF_SUBITEM` flag when they insert the columns. This establishes the relationship between sub-items and columns (columns can be re-ordered by the user).

I would also recommend that you reset `lvItem.mask` before adding sub-items because they only support a subset of the flags.